# Passing props to dynamic component in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm importing a map component dynamically with Next.js and I need to pass some data to it via props.

```
const MapWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("../Map"), {
    ssr: false,
    loading: () => <p>...</p>,
  });
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: And what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: the problem is that when I passed the data in props like I usually do, the component didn't read the data, so I thought maybe there is another way of passing data to dynamic components in next JS

Comment: *'> ... when I passed the data in props like I usually do, the component didn't read the data...'* Then, you've, probably, forgotten to paste here relevant piece of code.

Comment: How are you using `MapWithNoSSR`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would do like any other component:

```js
<MapWithNoSRR yourProp={data}></MapWithNoSRR>
```

Comment: This throws error in typescript

Comment: How 'yourProp' is passed into here:
`loading: () => <p>...</p>,`?